# using Calendar in java

Tags: java

Under the terms of the problem need to bring to the table name and the number of days of the week (except Sundays) every month, and year that the user selected in the combo box with the names and numbers of the month of the year. I found a solution:

```
public static List<String> getWeekDays(int year, int month) 
{
    List<String> weekDays = new ArrayList<>();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(year, month, 1);
int max = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
while (--max >= 0) 
    {
        switch (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
        {
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                weekDays.add("Пн#"+ Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                    break;
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                weekDays.add("Вт#"+ Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                    break;
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                weekDays.add("Ср#"+ Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                    break;
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                weekDays.add("Чт#"+ Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                    break;
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                weekDays.add("Пт#"+Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                    break;
            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                weekDays.add("Сб#"+ Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                    break;
        }
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
    return weekDays;
}
```

but it displays only the current month. Trying to change it monthly calendar.add (Calendar.MONTH, 1); but displays nonsense, that in November 2015 for 31 days and the month begins Tuesday.

```
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    System.out.println(" Date with month changed : " + sdfY.format(calendar.getTime()));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
    System.out.println(" Date with month changed : " + sdfM.format(calendar.getTime()));
    System.out.println(calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
```

In this piece displays the correct data per month in November, the year 2015, the first day of the week number 2. but the cycle for some reason begins to count from Monday 30th.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); i++ )
    {
        switch (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
        {
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                weekDays.add("Пн#"
                + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                    break;
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                weekDays.add("Вт#"
                + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                    break;
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                weekDays.add("Ср#" 
                + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                    break;
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                weekDays.add("Чт#"
                + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                    break;
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                weekDays.add("Пт#"
                + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                    break;
            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                weekDays.add("Сб#"
                + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                    break;
        }
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe someone will need

```
for(int i = 1; i <= calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); i++ )
        {
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i);
            switch (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
            {
                case Calendar.MONDAY:
                    weekDays.add("Пн#"
                    + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                        break;
                case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                    weekDays.add("Вт#"
                    + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                        break;
                case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                    weekDays.add("Ср#" 
                    + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                        break;
                case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                    weekDays.add("Чт#"
                    + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                        break;
                case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                    weekDays.add("Пт#"
                    + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                        break;
                case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                    weekDays.add("Сб#"
                    + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                        break;
            }
    }
```